# Is there a way to load Oblique font face in FreeType?

Tags: c++, windows, freetype, freetype2

Using Character Map UWP from Microsoft store and opening Tahoma font file shows 4 font faces in total. tahoma.ttf has Regular and Oblique font faces but when opening the font using FreeType num_faces is 1 and face style_name is "Regular". Does FreeType not support these font faces (you have to render them yourself using custom transforms)?.

Comment: Tahoma comes in [two styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/tahoma), tahoma.ttf provides Regular and tahomabd.ttf provides Bold.  Hard to guess where it came up with Oblique, it is an OpenType word and this is a TrueType font.  So yes, most probably synthesized.

Comment: @HansPassant Additionally: "_Since 2010, Ascender Corporation has offered italic and small caps versions of Tahoma._" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahoma_(typeface) and https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/tahoma/story)